# Is this considered a good convention? React, Redux, and Async Routing

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, url-routing

My team is using Dan Abramov's suggestion of a custom middleware for handling redux state which he mentions here, https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/99. We are also using nested async routes like this:

```
module.exports = {
  childRoutes: [
    require('./routes/list'),
    require('./routes/edit'),
  ]
}

module.exports = {
  path: 'organizations/:ID',
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./components/edit'))
    })
  }
};
```

We are using a GO server to handle our requests, so we are not doing server side rendering, as was the inspiration for the custom middleware above. The dispatch handlers connect to our components as such:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getOne,
})(EditOrganization)
```

The dispatch methods are then called within our `componentWillMount` lifecycle method like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
  getOne(ID)
}
```

My question is whether our setup is a good convention, combining async redux with nested async routes while using a custom middleware that I presume was intended for server side rendering. Any insights into this will be appreciated.